# how to use React-Native-Image-Picker?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use React-Native-Image-Picker. My question is that, is it necessary to eject the project to properly link this particular module. If no, does somebody know a link to a tutorial which can help me setup the module.

Comment: Eject? Are you using either create-react-native-app or expo? If you're using expo you can use these docs https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker.html

Comment: I am using create-react-native-app. I am able to install the module, but when I am running 'react-native link' nothing happens.

Comment: you can't work with native module with expo that created by create-react-native-app

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Which package that you currently use? This one https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker?

Comment: yes this is the one. Now the problem is I have used create-react-native-app to create the app(i believe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to eject to use a library requiring you to link. Enter `npm run eject` to eject the app. Once you eject, you will be able to link your library.

[Ejecting from create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md)

On a side note, I would recommend using Expo. Expo is similar to create-react-native-app, is more GUI-oriented. Expo also has an image picker as well as a lot of great apis you can use so you won't have to eject.

[CRNA vs Expo](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/153)

Comment: Two questions. First, if I eject will I still be able to code in react-native. Second, can I now move my existing project to Expo?

Comment: @GURSIMARSINGHCHAWLA Rather than ejecting, you can simply make your project into an Expo project. You won't have to change any code other than the code in root file (something like App.js). Just export default the root component and Expo will take care of the rest.